# How to read value of SAML attribute received from the IdP?

Tags: java, spring-security, spring-saml

I'm using Spring Security SAML 1.0.1, and I want to know the value of the SAML attribute whose name is "eduPersonAffiliation". I've coded a class which implements the `org.springframework.security.saml.userdetails.SAMLUserDetailsService` interface and in the `loadUserBySAML` method, I'm doing this:

```java
@Override
public Object loadUserBySAML(SAMLCredential credential) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
    String eduPersonAffiliationAttributeName = "";
    // We need to use the "name" of the attribute to retrieve the value (not the friendly name)
    for (Attribute attribute : credential.getAttributes()) {
        if ("eduPersonAffiliation".equals(attribute.getFriendlyName())) {
            eduPersonAffiliationAttributeName = attribute.getName();
        }
    }
    Person user = usersService.getUser(
             credential.getAttribute(eduPersonAffiliationAttributeName).WHAT_TO_CALL_HERE?);
    return loadUserByUser(user);
}
```

The `getUser` method expects a String which should be the login of the connected user. The question sounds stupid but how can I access the attribute value given the attribute name? I see a `org.opensaml.saml2.core.getAttributeValues` method that returns a `List<XMLObject>`. How to use it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 27, accepted):

**XmlObject** requires some unpacking to work with:

```
private String getAttributeValue(XMLObject attributeValue)
{
    return attributeValue == null ?
            null :
            attributeValue instanceof XSString ?
                    getStringAttributeValue((XSString) attributeValue) :
                    attributeValue instanceof XSAnyImpl ?
                            getAnyAttributeValue((XSAnyImpl) attributeValue) :
                            attributeValue.toString();
}

private String getStringAttributeValue(XSString attributeValue)
{
    return attributeValue.getValue();
}

private String getAnyAttributeValue(XSAnyImpl attributeValue)
{
    return attributeValue.getTextContent();
}
```

You can loop over the `List<XmlObject>` until you find the attribute you need to and then call the **getAttributeValue(XmlObject)** method above.

Depending on what these `XmlObject`s really are (**Attribute**, **AttributeValue**, etc.) you may need some portion of this algorithm to unpack them fully:

```
private final static String USERNAME_ATTRIBUTE_NAME = "urn:oid:0.9.2342.19200300.100.1.3"

private String getUsername(Assertion assertion)
{
    for (AttributeStatement attributeStatement : assertion.getAttributeStatements())
    {
        for (Attribute attribute : attributeStatement.getAttributes())
        {
            if (USERNAME_ATTRIBUTE_NAME.equals(attribute.getName()))
            {
                List<XMLObject> attributeValues = attribute.getAttributeValues();
                if (!attributeValues.isEmpty())
                {
                    return getAttributeValue(attributeValues.get(0));
                }
            }
        }
    }
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("no username attribute found");
}
```

In this case I'm using the standard OID for email address.  In practice this has to be configurable as various IdP's use different naming strategies.  This worked with Shibboleth IdP 3.

@StefanRasmusson's
[A Guide to OpenSAML](http://blog.samlsecurity.com/2014/09/opensaml-book-release.html?m=1) is what got me past the hump between getting SAML concepts and being able to implement my own SP.

Scott Cantor was also incredibly helpful to me on the shibboleth-users mailing list from topics ranging for configuration gaps to high-level security architectural questions.  The OpenSAML community (including Shibboleth) are very helpful and opinionated and I like that.

Comment: @GrégoireColbert does this work for you or get you closer to the answer.  I can iterate on it with you.

Comment: Thank you Alain, I'll try this tomorrow !

Comment: Good stuff. @ mention me and I'll jump in.

Comment: I get an infinite loop when using the`getAttributeValue` method. I suppose that the reading of the attribute depending on its class is done by a Spring Security SAML function, which is named differently? In other words, what would be the correct call for `getAttributeValue((XSString) attributeValue)`?

Comment: I'm looking for the correct method in https://wiki.shibboleth.net/confluence/display/OpenSAML/OSTwoUserManual but for the moment, I haven't found it.

Comment: @GrégoireColbert that's my fault.  I'm missing the other typed versions of that method.  Sorry.  I'll bring those in now.

Comment: @GrégoireColbert my bad for missing that. I tend to follow Uncle Bob's "extract 'til you drop" approach to get smaller methods. I need better names for those other two methods as they are in the same type hierarchy.  I'll fix that now.

Comment: @GrégoireColbert I've fixed it now. Thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: This is actually a very well written piece of code @Alain, worked like charm :)

Comment: Thank you @MilanDesai. That is very kind :)

Answer (score 2):

Another solution to access an attribute value is via SAMLCredential.getAttributeAsString(String name)

```
credential.getAttributeAsString(attribute.getName())
```