# Can't find replacement for SAMLCredential & SAMLUserdetailsservice in spring security saml 2.0.0.M31

Tags: spring-security, apache-commons-httpclient, opensaml

We are trying to upgrade opensaml to version 3 as a part of which we also need to upgrade spring security saml to 2.0.0.M31, as the earlier versions work with opensaml 2.6.4. We can't find replacement for below classes in the code, these classes were removed during a cleanup but can't find any details other than this. Any help is appreciated.

SAMLCredential
SAMLUserDetailsService

Comment: maybe this can help idk
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-saml/issues/309
https://stackoverflow.com/a/33678256/10479742